# Elements will not add to Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm trying to load in two txt files and compare the differences between the two. More specifically I'm looping through one file per line and comparing it to every line in another txt file.

For the most part everything is working but I have found that I'm only able to access the array within the `lr.on('line')` function. However I have declared the array in the global scope.

Here is the code:

```js
var LineByLineReader = require('line-by-line');
var lr = new LineByLineReader('phones.txt');
var lr2 = new LineByLineReader('wor.txt');


var phoneArray = [];
var worArray = [];

lr.on('error', function(err){
   if(err){
       console.log("We have found the following error: " + err);
   }
});

lr2.on('error', function(err){
   if(err){
       console.log("We have found the following error: " + err);
   }
});
 
lr.on('line', function(line){
   phoneArray.push(line);
});

lr2.on('line', function(line){
   worArray.push(line);
});

for(var i = 0; i < phoneArray.length; i++){
        for(var x = 0; x < worArray.length; x++){
            if(array1[i] === array2[x]){
                console.log("Found Match: " + array2[x]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Whare are array1[i] and array[2] inside the for loop?Where you define them?Maybe you mean phoneArray and worArray?

Comment: Check the order of execution, are you looping before it's finished appending lines? Is there some kind of callback from the ` `LineByLineReader` when it's complete?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just forgot to use the right variables names inside your for loop?
And you just need this? :

```
if(phoneArray[i] === worArray[x]){
                console.log("Found Match: " + worArray[x]);
```

Comment: That was a mistake on my part.